# How to call different methods in a controller in OData

Tags: odata

I am using web api 2.2 odata v4.0. I have a controller which has 3 methods.
For example `GetA()`, `GetB()` and `GetC()`. 
Which code should I use so that I will be able to call individual methods from the url ? 
Also, how can I call a method `GetA()`? - as `Get()` is the default method that is being called in `ODataController`.

I used the code,

```
ODataRoute route = config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata",GetModel());
route.MapODataRouteAttributes(config); // This line threw an error sowing route does not have the method 
MapODataRouteAttributes()
```

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need GetA(), GetB() and GetC() to do ? Are they for getting specific properties A, B and C? If so, you can take a look at the [ODAtaAttributeRoutingSample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataAttributeRoutingSample/). And if you want to know more about Web API OData, you can take a look at [Sample Service implemented with Web API](https://github.com/OData/Samples) which is a complete project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with the Action Attributes to specify other functions then those following the default rules.

[routing with attributes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)